# Expected Value of First Number over 12

Tags: probability, expected-value, recursion

We roll a fair 6 sided die and keep a running sum $S$ of the rolls so far. We stop as soon as $S$ is greater than 12. What is the expected value for $S$.

The simplest approach I can think of is using states: Let $E_i$ denote the expected end result given that the sum is currently $i$, we want $E_0$. Then:

$$E_i=\frac{1}{6}(E_{i+1}+\dots E_{i+6}), \forall 0\leq i\leq 12$$ and for $i>12$, we simply have $E_i=i$. This gives 12 independent linear equations with 12 unknowns $E_0,E_1,\dots, E_{12}$, so we could solve for $E_0$. Is there a clean way to do this? I've tried adding all the equations up and also the shifting indices trick, e.g. $E_{i+1}-E_i=\frac{1}{6}(E_{i+7}-E_{i+1})$, but I can't see how to get nice simplification. Perhaps there is not a nice simplification. But the symmetry in the system does make me think there could be. Any ideas?

Also if anyone has any other approaches besides this algebraic approach (e.g. a probability based approach with less computation), that would also be appreciated. Thanks!

Source: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Probability/RollingDie.shtml (this has a solution, but it is incorrect)

Comment: Just go backwards.  $E_{12}=15.5$ (why)?  So now you can find $E_{11}$ and that leads to $E_{10}$ and then...

Comment: Note:  you are certainly right the the linked solution is incorrect. Kind of obviously so.  Backwards induction gives $14.69021934$ which matches what the link claims for the simulated result.

Comment: Same result of $\frac{191864459829}{6^{13}}$ doing a forward calculation of the probabilities

Comment: thanks for the comments. going backwards does shorten the computation substantially, and it does seem there is no nice closed form solution, despite the symmetry.